# Unityにて、スマートフォン端末のスピーカー音量とミュートスイッチの値を取得したい

Tags: android, ios, unity3d

Unity4.6を使用してiOS/Android向けアプリを開発しています。
audioSource.Play()　でサウンドを鳴らし、
yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);　で鳴っている間待機させています。

端末側のスピーカーの音量がゼロの時、またはiOSでミュートスイッチがオンになっている時は
音を鳴らさず（待機せず）先に進ませたいのですが、
Unityのスクリプトからスピーカーにアクセスする方法はあるのでしょうか？
（あくまで音量やスイッチの「値の取得」のみで、変更はしなくて構いません）
また、ネイティブプラグインなら対処できるのでしょうか？

調べた結果マイクの音量取得はあったのですが、スピーカーの情報が見付からず質問させて頂きました。
何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えて頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

Audioはやったことないので間違っているかもしれませんが、AudioListenerというのがあるようです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859693/how-do-i-mute-the-audio-in-unity-3d

> AudioListener.volume = 0;

.volumeを0にできるので、もしかしたら、.volume==0の判別ができるかもしれません。